# How do I insert a newline in a multiline TextBox after mouse click in the TextBox?

Tags: c#, string, textbox, multiline

When the user clicks on the multiline textbox. My Forms App should insert a new line, at the end of the current clicked line.

For example, these are the lines in my textbox:

```
-Hallo
-Dear
-Kindly
```

If the User clicks at the second line (-Dear), the value in my textbox should be:

```
-Hallo
-Dear

-Kindly
```

One of my (failed) attempts which doesn't insert the new-line:

```
int line = txtProjects.GetLineFromCharIndex(txtProjects.SelectionStart);
txtProjects.Lines[line] = txtProjects.Lines[line].Insert(txtProjects.Lines[line].Length, Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append something to an array you have to recreate it since arrays are fixed sized. You could use LINQ:

```
int lineCount = txtProjects.GetLineFromCharIndex(txtProjects.SelectionStart) + 1; // zero based
string[] lines = txtProjects.Lines;
txtProjects.Lines = lines 
    .Take(lineCount)
    .Concat(new[] {"\n"})
    .Concat(lines.Skip(lineCount))
    .ToArray();
```

a probably more readable approach is using  `List<string>.Insert`:

```
List<string> lines = txtProjects.Lines.ToList();
lines.Insert(lineCount, "");  //  null works also
txtProjects.Lines = lines.ToArray();
```

---

If you want to keep the "cursor"-position, you could use `TextBox.Select`:

```
private void txtProjects_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int cursorPos = txtProjects.SelectionStart;
    int lineCount = txtProjects.GetLineFromCharIndex(cursorPos) + 1; // zero based
    List<string> lines = txtProjects.Lines.ToList();
    lines.Insert(lineCount, null);
    txtProjects.Lines = lines.ToArray();
    txtProjects.Select(cursorPos, 0);
}
```

Comment: it adds 2 new lines?

Comment: @ISeeSharp: i've already replaced `.Concat(new[] {Environment.NewLine})` with `.Concat(new[] {"\n"})`. Have you noticed it? `Environment.NewLine` will add two lines because both `\r` and `\n` are treated as line separator chars.

Comment: @ISeeSharp: i've edited my answer to show a more readable approach with a `List<T>`.

Comment: why do the cursor change? Its position return to the first position of the first line.

Comment: @ISeeSharp: Ive edited my answer to show a complete sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var p = TextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex[TextBox1.SelectionStart];
List<string> str = new List<string>();
str.AddRange(TextBox1.Lines);
str.Insert(p + 1, "");
TextBox1.Text = "";
foreach (void st_loopVariable in str) {
    st = st_loopVariable;
    TextBox1.Text += st + Constants.vbNewLine;
}
```

It was working on vb. I converted it to C# so there can be some syntax errors.